# Center align pagination bar

Tags: css

I have a problem with my pagination bar - I can't center this bar...

Here is my code:

```
<div style="pagination">
    <a href="#" class="page gradient">first</a><a href=
    "#" class="page gradient">2</a><a href="#" class=
    "page gradient">3</a><span class=
    "page active">4</span><a href="#" class=
    "page gradient">5</a><a href="#" class=
    "page gradient">6</a><a href="#" class=
    "page gradient">last</a>
</div>
<style>
.pagination {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #666;
    font: 14px/24px sans-serif;
}

.page {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 9px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8), 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    font-size: .875em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #717171;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 1);
}

.page:hover, .page.gradient:hover {
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FEFEFE), to(#f0f0f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#FEFEFE, #f0f0f0);
}

.page.active {
    border: none;
    background: #616161;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8);
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.page.gradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f8f8f8), to(#e9e9e9));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#f8f8f8, #e9e9e9);
}

.pagination.dark {
    background: #414449;
    color: #feffff;
}

.page.dark {
    border: solid 1px #32373b;
    background: #3e4347;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    color: #feffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.page.dark:hover, .page.dark.gradient:hover {
    background: #3d4f5d;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#547085), to(#3d4f5d));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#547085, #3d4f5d);
}

.page.dark.active {
    border: none;
    background: #2f3237;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.page.dark.gradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#565b5f), to(#3e4347));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#565b5f, #3e4347);
}
</style>
```

I tried everything but it doesn't work...
I tried everything but it doesn't work...

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gvq8reao/).
Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An extra surrounding element ('container') may help here. You can make the bar `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on the parent to center the bar:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
```

Note that you wrote `style="pagination"` in your code, which should of course be `class="pagination"`, otherwise the CSS won't be applied to the element at all.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvq8reao/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.pagination {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #666;
    font: 14px/24px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.page {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 9px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8), 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    font-size: .875em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #717171;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 1);
}

.page:hover, .page.gradient:hover {
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FEFEFE), to(#f0f0f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#FEFEFE, #f0f0f0);
}

.page.active {
    border: none;
    background: #616161;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8);
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.page.gradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f8f8f8), to(#e9e9e9));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#f8f8f8, #e9e9e9);
}

.pagination.dark {
    background: #414449;
    color: #feffff;
}

.page.dark {
    border: solid 1px #32373b;
    background: #3e4347;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    color: #feffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.page.dark:hover, .page.dark.gradient:hover {
    background: #3d4f5d;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#547085), to(#3d4f5d));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#547085, #3d4f5d);
}

.page.dark.active {
    border: none;
    background: #2f3237;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.page.dark.gradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#565b5f), to(#3e4347));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#565b5f, #3e4347);
}
```

```html
 <div class="pagination">
  <a href="#" class="page gradient">first</a><a href=
  "#" class="page gradient">2</a><a href="#" class=
  "page gradient">3</a><span class=
  "page active">4</span><a href="#" class=
  "page gradient">5</a><a href="#" class=
  "page gradient">6</a><a href="#" class=
  "page gradient">last</a>
 </div>
```